# Unable to bind with <apex:inputField>

Tags: apex, visualforce, inputfield, databinding

I have some VF code that is working - basically, I have a custom object `form` and I am updating the fields via components like this:

```
 <apex:repeat value="{!jewishEducationalHistoryFields}"   var="fieldAPI" >
   <apex:variable value="{!requiredMap[fieldAPI.Field_API_Name__c]}" var="reqd">
      <apex:outputLabel value="{!labelMap[fieldAPI.Field_API_Name__c]}" html-class="field-label"/>
      <apex:inputField required="{!reqd}" html-class="{!fieldAPI.Field_CSS__c}" value="{!form[fieldAPI.Field_API_Name__c]}" />
  </apex:variable>
```

Note the syntax in the `inputField` tag. Note that the variable `fieldAPI.Field_API_Name__c` is a String. 
This is working.

If I modify the syntax slightly, and instead pass in a String variable directly, like below, then I get the classic error message that inputfield can only be used with sObjects, and it complains specifically about this binding.

```
<apex:variable value="Name_of_School__c" var="localFieldName">
    <apex:variable value="{!requiredMap[localFieldName]}" var="reqd">
      <apex:outputLabel value="{!labelMap[localFieldName]}" html-class="field-label" />
      <apex:inputField required="{!reqd}" value="{!form[localFieldName]}" />
    </apex:variable>
</apex:variable>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Note: I have also tried storing the literal value `Name_of_School__c` in a String variable on the controller and passing that in, and I get the same error.

Comment: You need to extract the info from Name of school and put it in an iterable

Comment: You can use inputText

Comment: @Eric I tried doing that by putting it in a String and got the same result. Does it need to be a SF object, not just a string?

Comment: You are missing the {!} as well right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `<apex:inputText required="{!reqd}" value="{!form[localFieldName]}" />` as `<apex:inputField/>` is applicable to SObjects.

For more info, refer [apex:inputText](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_inputText.htm)

Answer (score -2):

As you told form is a sObject here, then you can bind sObject fields dynamically. check this link : http://forceschool.blogspot.in/2011/06/dynamic-binding-when-object-name-is.html

Comment: I am not having trouble with that one - form[] syntax is working for me. It is the form[localFieldName] syntax which is not working ..

Comment: form is a map here?

Comment: form is a custom sObject, not a map.

Comment: I think you have to check this link http://forceschool.blogspot.in/2011/06/dynamic-binding-when-object-name-is.html.